# what should I do if after turning on the bot after 4 minutes, the buttons stop working?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm making a discord bot on python using discordpy. Here are the imports:
import discord
from random import randint
import json
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.User interface import button, view

Here is an example of a button:

```
class ButtonSandStone8(Button):
    def __init__(self,label):
        super().__init__(label=label,style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey,custom_id='SandStone_btn8')

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        global queue8
        if "<@" + str(interaction.user.id) + ">" + "\n"+ "\n"+ "\n" in queue8:
            global lobby_voice8
            global ct8
            global t8
            global voice_ct8
            global voice_t8
            voice_state = interaction.user.voice

            if voice_state is None:
                embed = discord.Embed(description='Вы должны зайти в войс, чтобы участвовать!',color=discord.Color.dark_grey())
                return await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)

            elif interaction.user.voice.channel.id == lobby_voice8:
                global voices8
                if len(queue8)-10 < 10:
                    embed = discord.Embed(description='Очередь не полная!',color=discord.Color.dark_grey())
                    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)

                elif len(queue8)-10 == 10 and interaction.user not in voices8 and "<@" + str(interaction.user.id) + ">" + "\n"+ "\n"+ "\n" in queue8:
                    voices8.append(interaction.user)
                    global SandStone8
                    global Rust8
                    global Zone98
                    global Province8
                    global Breeze8
                    SandStone8 += 1
                    if len(voices8) < 10:
                        embed = discord.Embed(description='+1 голос за карту SandStone', color=discord.Color.dark_grey())
                        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)

                    if len(voices8) == 10:
                        global msg8
                        await msg8.delete()
                        if SandStone8 > Rust8 and SandStone8 > Zone98 and SandStone8 > Breeze8 and SandStone8 > Province8:
                            await distribution_sandstone8(interaction)

                        elif Rust8 > SandStone8 and Rust8 > Zone98 and Rust8 > Breeze8 and Rust8 > Province8:
                            await distribution_rust8(interaction)

                        elif Zone98 > SandStone8 and Zone98 > Rust8 and Zone98 > Province8 and Zone98 > Breeze8:
                            await distribution_zone98(interaction)

                        elif Province8 > SandStone8 and Province8 > Rust8 and Province8 > Zone98 and Province8 > Breeze8:
                            await distribution_province8(interaction)

                        elif Breeze8 > SandStone8 and Breeze8 > Rust8 and Breeze8 > Zone98 and Breeze8 > Province8:
                            await distribution_breeze8(interaction)

                        else:
                            voices8.clear()
                            SandStone8 = 0
                            Rust8 = 0
                            Zone98 = 0
                            Province8 = 0
                            Breeze8 = 0
                            embed = discord.Embed(description='Ничья! Голосование повторяется', color=discord.Color.dark_grey())
                            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, delete_after=180)

            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(description='Вы подключены не к тому голосовому каналу!',color=discord.Color.dark_grey())
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)

        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(description='Вас нет в очереди чтобы голосовать!',color=discord.Color.red())
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
```

Here is an example of a button call:

```
SandStone_btn8 = ButtonSandStone8("1.SandStone")
w = View()
w.add_item(SandStone_btn8)
```

My idea is to somehow restart the bot every 3 minutes, but maybe there is another way to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for the `timeout` kwarg to `View` is 180, meaning the view times out after 180 seconds. If you want a different timeout, pass a value for it. A value of `None` means it doesn't time out.

```py
View(timeout=None)
```

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=view#discord.ui.View.timeout

> The timeout in seconds from last interaction with the UI before no longer accepting input. If None then there is no timeout.

However, this is only as long as your bot is running, and all components will stop working when you restart your bot. If you want to avoid this, there's an official example on how to make persistent views. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py